# Join Two queries with different declarations

Tags: subquery, cte

I need to join two different queries to get some columns from both. The first one has a CTE.

Query1:

```
   WITH StatusChanges AS 
(
    SELECT 
       HistoryID,PartID,Status, DateAdded, 
       rnAsset = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartID ORDER BY DateAdded) 
    FROM aAssetHistory
) SELECT 
    A.isMarketed,A.AssetDescription,A.aPartID,A.SerialNumber,A.PartNumber,
    A.Location,A.Vintage,Ap.Fund,A.ProjectNumber,AP.ProjectName ,
    (
       SELECT Top 1 Disposition 
       FROM aAssetDisposition AD 
       WHERE (A.aPartid = AD.AssetID)) As Disposition, A.LocStatus ,
          CASE 
             WHEN A.LocStatus='In Repair' THEN EstimatedCompletion 
             WHEN A.LocStatus like '%lease%' THEN IIF(ProjectedReDeliveryDate='1/1/1900',LeaseExpiry,ProjectedReDeliveryDate)  
             WHEN A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed' THEN SC.DateAdded 
          END 'Available',A.AssetComment, 
          Cast(ISNULL((SELECT Top 1 1 
                       FROM aAssetMarketingDocuments AMDocs 
                       WHERE A.aPartid=AMDocs.aPartid),0) As bit
       ) Attachment 
    FROM aAsset A  
INNER JOIN aProject AP On A.ProjectNumber=AP.ProjectNumber 
LEFT JOIN aAsset ParentA  On A.ParentACPartID=ParentA.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN aEngineShop ES ON A.LocStatus='In Repair' AND ES.PartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN vLeasedAsset LA ON A.LocStatus like '%lease%' AND LA.aPartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT SC1.PartID, SC1.DateAdded,RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SC1.PartID ORDER BY SC1.DateAdded DESC) 
          FROM StatusChanges SC1 
          LEFT JOIN StatusChanges SC2 ON SC1.PartID=SC2.PartID AND SC2.rnAsset=SC1.rnAsset-1 
          WHERE (SC1.Status<>SC2.Status OR SC2.HistoryID IS NULL)) SC 
ON (A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed') AND A.aPartid=SC.PartID AND SC.rn = 1 
WHERE ((A.isMarketed=1 AND (ParentA.isMarketed IS NULL OR ParentA.isMarketed=0)) )
```

Query2:

```
 SELECT 
    A.[AssetMarketingID],B.PartID, aCompany.Company 'PotentialCustomer', A.isActive, 
    ISNULL(CAST(Lease AS bit),0) 'Lease', ISNULL(CAST(Exchange AS bit),0) 'Exchange', 
    ISNULL(CAST(Sale AS bit),0) 'Sale' ,DocumentStage,ContactTB.FirstName + ' ' + ContactTB.LastName 'Contact', 
    A.ContactDate,A.Status,B.Amount, A.DateCreated, [Notes] 
FROM aAssetMarketing A 
LEFT JOIN aAssetMarketingAssets B ON A.AssetMarketingID=B.AssetMarketingID 
LEFT JOIN aCompany On [PotentialCustomerID]=COid 
LEFT JOIN aCompanyContact ContactTB ON [MarketingContactID]=ContactID 
LEFT JOIN (
          select AssetMarketingID,max(case when DealStructure = 'Exchange' then 1 ELSE 0 end) Exchange, 
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Lease' then 1 Else 0 end) Lease, 
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Sale' then 1 Else 0 end) Sale 
FROM [aAssetMarketingDealStructure] 
GROUP BY AssetMarketingID) DS     
    ON DS.AssetMarketingID=A.AssetMarketingID 
ORDER BY A.ContactDate DESC
```

Comment: What columns do you want to return?  What is/are the join column(s) between the two results?  Have you considered writing one result out to a temp table and doing a join to that?

Comment: Both must be joined by PartID. Columns: A.SerialNumber, A.PartNumber, Location, Ap.Fund, Disposition, aCompany.Company 'PotentialCustomer', DocumentStage, Lease, Sale, Etc.

Comment: I tried that but I get some errors related with the CTE.

Comment: Did you mean SELECT * FROM (Query1) Temp1, excluding from Query1 "WITH StatusChanges AS" and "FROM StatusChanges SC1 
LEFT JOIN StatusChanges SC2 ON SC1.PartID=SC2.PartID AND SC2.rnAsset=SC1.rnAsset-1 
WHERE (SC1.Status<>SC2.Status OR SC2.HistoryID IS NULL)) SC 
ON (A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed') AND A.aPartid=SC.PartID AND SC.rn = 1 
WHERE ((A.isMarketed=1 AND (ParentA.isMarketed IS NULL OR ParentA.isMarketed=0)) )"

Comment: Ok, got it. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   WITH StatusChanges AS 
(
    SELECT 
       HistoryID,PartID,Status, DateAdded, 
       rnAsset = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartID ORDER BY DateAdded) 
    FROM aAssetHistory
) SELECT 
    A.isMarketed,A.AssetDescription,A.aPartID,A.SerialNumber,A.PartNumber,
    A.Location,A.Vintage,Ap.Fund,A.ProjectNumber,AP.ProjectName ,
    (
       SELECT Top 1 Disposition 
       FROM aAssetDisposition AD 
       WHERE (A.aPartid = AD.AssetID)) As Disposition, A.LocStatus ,
          CASE 
             WHEN A.LocStatus='In Repair' THEN EstimatedCompletion 
             WHEN A.LocStatus like '%lease%' THEN IIF(ProjectedReDeliveryDate='1/1/1900',LeaseExpiry,ProjectedReDeliveryDate)  
             WHEN A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed' THEN SC.DateAdded 
          END 'Available',A.AssetComment, 
          Cast(ISNULL((SELECT Top 1 1 
                       FROM aAssetMarketingDocuments AMDocs 
                       WHERE A.aPartid=AMDocs.aPartid),0) As bit
       ) Attachment 
    INTO #tmp
    FROM aAsset A  
INNER JOIN aProject AP On A.ProjectNumber=AP.ProjectNumber 
LEFT JOIN aAsset ParentA  On A.ParentACPartID=ParentA.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN aEngineShop ES ON A.LocStatus='In Repair' AND ES.PartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN vLeasedAsset LA ON A.LocStatus like '%lease%' AND LA.aPartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT SC1.PartID, SC1.DateAdded,RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SC1.PartID ORDER BY SC1.DateAdded DESC) 
          FROM StatusChanges SC1 
          LEFT JOIN StatusChanges SC2 ON SC1.PartID=SC2.PartID AND SC2.rnAsset=SC1.rnAsset-1 
          WHERE (SC1.Status<>SC2.Status OR SC2.HistoryID IS NULL)) SC 
ON (A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed') AND A.aPartid=SC.PartID AND SC.rn = 1 
WHERE ((A.isMarketed=1 AND (ParentA.isMarketed IS NULL OR ParentA.isMarketed=0)) )
```

Query2:

```
SELECT 
    A.[AssetMarketingID],B.PartID, aCompany.Company 'PotentialCustomer', A.isActive, 
    ISNULL(CAST(Lease AS bit),0) 'Lease', ISNULL(CAST(Exchange AS bit),0) 'Exchange', 
    ISNULL(CAST(Sale AS bit),0) 'Sale' ,DocumentStage,ContactTB.FirstName + ' ' + ContactTB.LastName 'Contact', 
    A.ContactDate,A.Status,B.Amount, A.DateCreated, [Notes] 
FROM aAssetMarketing A 
LEFT JOIN aAssetMarketingAssets B ON A.AssetMarketingID=B.AssetMarketingID 
LEFT JOIN aCompany On [PotentialCustomerID]=COid 
LEFT JOIN aCompanyContact ContactTB ON [MarketingContactID]=ContactID 
LEFT JOIN (
          select AssetMarketingID,max(case when DealStructure = 'Exchange' then 1 ELSE 0 end) Exchange, 
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Lease' then 1 Else 0 end) Lease, 
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Sale' then 1 Else 0 end) Sale 
FROM [aAssetMarketingDealStructure] 
JOIN #tmp A ON 
A.SerialNumber, A.PartNumber, Location, A.Fund, Disposition, DocumentStage, Lease, Sale
GROUP BY AssetMarketingID) DS     
    ON DS.AssetMarketingID=A.AssetMarketingID 
ORDER BY A.ContactDate DESC
```

Comment: I placed the INTO keyword on the line prior to the FROM of the CTE and it launched that: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: Sorry, the cte is not the base of your select, I have corrected INTO

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    WITH StatusChanges AS 
(
    SELECT HistoryID,PartID,Status, DateAdded, rnAsset = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartID ORDER BY DateAdded) 
    FROM aAssetHistory
) 

    SELECT X.SerialNumber, X.PartNumber, X.ProjectName, X.ProjectNumber, X.AssetDescription, X.Available, X.Location, X.LocStatus, X.AssetComment, X.Disposition, X.Fund, X.isMarketed,
                Y.PotentialCustomer, Y.Lease, Y.Exchange, Y.Sale, Y.DocumentStage, Y.Contact, Y.ContactDate, Y.Amount, Y.Notes  
FROM 
(
SELECT A.isMarketed,A.AssetDescription,A.aPartID,A.SerialNumber,A.PartNumber,
   A.Location,A.Vintage,Ap.Fund,A.ProjectNumber,AP.ProjectName ,
(SELECT Top 1 Disposition FROM aAssetDisposition AD WHERE (A.aPartid = AD.AssetID)) As Disposition, A.LocStatus ,
  CASE 
     WHEN A.LocStatus='In Repair' THEN EstimatedCompletion 
     WHEN A.LocStatus like '%lease%' THEN IIF(ProjectedReDeliveryDate='1/1/1900',LeaseExpiry,ProjectedReDeliveryDate)    
     WHEN A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed' THEN SC.DateAdded 
   END 'Available'
 ,A.AssetComment, Cast(ISNULL((SELECT Top 1 1 FROM aAssetMarketingDocuments AMDocs WHERE A.aPartid = AMDocs.aPartid),0) As bit) Attachment
FROM aAsset A  
INNER JOIN aProject AP On A.ProjectNumber=AP.ProjectNumber 
LEFT JOIN aAsset ParentA  On A.ParentACPartID=ParentA.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN aEngineShop ES ON A.LocStatus='In Repair' AND ES.PartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN vLeasedAsset LA ON A.LocStatus like '%lease%' AND LA.aPartID=A.aPartid 
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT SC1.PartID, SC1.DateAdded,RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SC1.PartID ORDER BY SC1.DateAdded DESC)
          FROM StatusChanges SC1
          LEFT JOIN StatusChanges SC2 ON SC1.PartID=SC2.PartID AND SC2.rnAsset=SC1.rnAsset-1
          WHERE (SC1.Status<>SC2.Status OR SC2.HistoryID IS NULL)) SC  
ON (A.LocStatus='Stored' OR A.LocStatus='Marketed') AND A.aPartid=SC.PartID AND SC.rn = 1 
WHERE ((A.isMarketed=1 AND (ParentA.isMarketed IS NULL OR ParentA.isMarketed=0)))
) X LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT A.[AssetMarketingID],B.PartID, aCompany.Company 'PotentialCustomer', A.isActive, 
     ISNULL(CAST(Lease AS bit),0) 'Lease', ISNULL(CAST(Exchange AS bit),0) 'Exchange', 
     ISNULL(CAST(Sale AS bit),0) 'Sale' ,DocumentStage,ContactTB.FirstName + ' ' + ContactTB.LastName 'Contact', A.ContactDate,A.Status,B.Amount, A.DateCreated, [Notes] 
FROM aAssetMarketing A 
LEFT JOIN aAssetMarketingAssets B ON A.AssetMarketingID=B.AssetMarketingID 
LEFT JOIN aCompany On [PotentialCustomerID]=COid 
LEFT JOIN aCompanyContact ContactTB ON [MarketingContactID]=ContactID 
LEFT JOIN (
          select AssetMarketingID,
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Exchange' then 1 ELSE 0 end) Exchange, 
          max(case when DealStructure = 'Lease' then 1 Else 0 end) Lease, max(case when DealStructure = 'Sale' then 1 Else 0 end) Sale 
FROM [aAssetMarketingDealStructure]
GROUP BY AssetMarketingID) DS ON DS.AssetMarketingID=A.AssetMarketingID 
) Y 
On X.aPartid = Y.PartID
```